# Clistview Yii framework Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, clistview

I have a problem in using Ajax and ClistView.

I have 2 posts , each one has comments, the first one has 3 comments, the second one  ,  one comment.

Post A

Link to Comments(3)

Post B

Link to Comments(1)

When I click  on Link to Comments(3),  I got the following,  as expected

Post A

Comment 1

Comment 2

Comment 3

Post B

Link to Comments(1)

But when I click on comments(1), I got

Post A

Comment 1 of post B

Post B

So the comment of Post B  displays under the post A.

How can I solve the problem ?

The code of the Ajax link is the following

```
<?php           

            echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Test request', 
            array($url_replace),
            array(
            'update'=>'#req_res_loading',
            'beforeSend' => 'function() {           
            $("#maindiv").addClass("loading");
            }',
            'complete' => 'function() {
                $("#maindiv").removeClass("loading");
            }',        
            )
            );
        echo '<div id="req_res_loading">...</div>';

        ?>
```

and the comments are called through the Clistview command

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_comment',
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
)); ?>
```

my _comments view contains the following

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_comment',
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
)); ?>
```

and my _comment view contains the following

```
<div class="comment">


    <div class="content">
        <?php
            $this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
            echo $data->content;
            $this->endWidget();
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the post view is renderPartial with this code

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">
        <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->title), $data->url); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
        posted by <?php echo $data->author->username . ' on ' . date('F j, Y',$data->create_time); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
            $this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
            echo $data->content;
            $this->endWidget();
        ?>

    </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: where is ajax success part? i mean you are loading the response in some div. show more code.

Comment: @kumar_v, I updated my post with the required code

Comment: I think div with id = req_res_loading is existing more than one time. is it right? if so, change id with unique id.

Comment: Yes you are right but how can I change it  with unique id ?  @kumar_v

Comment: hope you have record id. then append id with div id.

Comment: @kumar_v  Sorry I dont understand

Comment: i mean add your post id in div id.